# DevExpress GridView Scroll Bar (adjusting Grid Left Coord to bring focused column in the center of the grid)

Tags: c#, .net, focus, devexpress, scrollbar

I have a form which has a DevExpress GridView. The GridView has close to 100 columns. Currently, at a time I show 30 columns to the user and the rest of the columns can be accessed by scrolling on the right hand side.

Instead of scrolling, I want to implement a functionality such that I enter a value(Column Number) in a textbox and click a button (for example), it should navigate to that particular column in the gridView.

So far, I am able to implement the following:

1. If suppose, in the beginning i show columns 1-30 and search column 45 it shows the result with the column selected at the extreme right.
2. If suppose, in the beginning i have columns 20-50 columns shown to the user and search column 10, it shows in the extreme right.

I want to implement in such a way that whenever I search a column, it should not show in the extreme right or left but should show in the center.

Please check the code given below. The logic seems to be fine but it is not working correctly.

```
 private void SetLeftCoord(int toBeFocusedIndex)
    {
        int currLeftEndColIndex = gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.LeftCoord / gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.VisibleColumns[0].Width;

        int currRightEndColIndex = currLeftEndColIndex - 1 + GetVisibleColumnCount(gvVisualizeNextGenSequence);

        if (toBeFocusedIndex < currRightEndColIndex && toBeFocusedIndex > currLeftEndColIndex)
        {
            int difference = toBeFocusedIndex - currLeftEndColIndex;
            gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.LeftCoord +=
                (difference * gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.VisibleColumns[0].Width) -
                (GetVisibleColumnCount(gvVisualizeNextGenSequence) / 2) * gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.VisibleColumns[0].Width;
        }
        if (toBeFocusedIndex < (GetVisibleColumnCount(gvVisualizeNextGenSequence) / 2) ||
          toBeFocusedIndex > gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.VisibleColumns.Count - (GetVisibleColumnCount(gvVisualizeNextGenSequence) / 2))
        { }

        if (toBeFocusedIndex < currLeftEndColIndex)
        { gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.LeftCoord -= (GetVisibleColumnCount(gvVisualizeNextGenSequence) / 2) * gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.VisibleColumns[0].Width; }

        if (toBeFocusedIndex > currRightEndColIndex)
        { gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.LeftCoord += (GetVisibleColumnCount(gvVisualizeNextGenSequence) / 2) * gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.VisibleColumns[0].Width; }


        gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.FocusedColumn = gvVisualizeNextGenSequence.Columns["Column" + toBeFocusedIndex];


    }
```

Is there any other way to do this?
"at any point of time, my focused column should be in the center of the grid"

Thanks

Mangesh Vilas Kaslikar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gridview1.LeftCoord = (gridview1.FocusedColumn.VisibleIndex - visibleColumnsCount / 2) * gridview1.VisibleColumns[0].Width;

Visiblecolumnscount = // count of currently visible columns in the view 

  public int GetVisibleColumnCount(GridView view)
        {
            GridViewInfo info = view.GetViewInfo() as GridViewInfo;
            int visibleColumnCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < view.VisibleColumns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (info.GetColumnLeftCoord(view.GetVisibleColumn(i))
                    < view.ViewRect.Width - info.ViewRects.IndicatorWidth)

                    visibleColumnCount++;
            }
            return visibleColumnCount;
        }
```